# C# Reflection on a Type Object

Tags: c#, reflection

**To clarify, yes, I do want to list the properties and values of a System.Type object, which is why I'm using "typeof(Type).GetProperties()" instead of "TheTypeObj.GetProperties()".**

I'm trying to list all the property names and values of a **Type** object, but I'm getting an error. This is what I have so far:

```
using System.Reflection;

public static string list_properties(Type TheTypeObj)
{
    var Str = "\n";
    object Name, Value;
    foreach (var ThePropertyInfo in typeof(Type).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public))
    {
        Name = ThePropertyInfo.Name;
        Value = ThePropertyInfo.GetValue(TheTypeObj); //this line throws the error
        Str += Name + ": " + Value.ToString() + "\n";
    }
    return Str;
}
```

When I use it in context:

```
list_properties((new Object()).GetType());
```

I get this error:

> **Value = ThePropertyInfo.GetValue(TheTypeObj);**
>
> InvalidOperationException: Method may only be called on a Type for
> which Type.IsGenericParameter is true.

How do I list the properties and values of a **Type** object?

Comment: `typeof(Type)` probably should be `TheTypeObj`. I assume you want to reflect on the members of the type instance passed in, not `System.Type` itself.

Comment: @madreflection Yes, I specifically want to look at the properties of System.Type

Comment: There's no way to tell via reflection if a property can be accessed on some instances and not others because it's a runtime determination. Because you're reflecting on a known type, you can exclude those properties by name if `IsGenericParameter` is not true. Unfortunately, if properties that are inaccessible without meeting some *other* condition are added in the future, it'll break again. The best you can do to future-proof it from such changes is to wrap each call to `GetValue` in a try/catch.

Comment: What is the name of the property on the failure? What type is it exactly? Can you enumerate the values without getting the value? I say this because you may have to handle unique types specifically and not in a generic/standard methodology.

Comment: Use LINQPad to do `typeof(Type).Dump()` and see the errors that are displayed for generic only properties.